# Weird requests duplication in Mean.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean.io

I have cloned a repository from Github that works perfectly in other computers (MacOS X and Windows) But for some reason I can't log in. It is a base Mean.io project. It loads perfectly. I register normally, but when I try to login, it redirects me to /. The user is stored correctly in mongo so I do not know / understand what's going on. I have also debugged with node-inspector but gotten no results.

I have found out from debugging that that in my computer the code behaves wrong in this portion (packages/users/public/controllers/meanUser.js):

```
// authentication OK
$scope.loginError = 0;
$rootScope.user = response.user; // here $scope.global.authenticated is false
$rootScope.$emit('loggedin');    // $scope.global.authenticated is set to true
if (response.redirect) { // here $scope.global.authenticated is false again and it shouldn't but haven't been able to find out what's the problem
```

This is my package.json

```
"name": "mean",
  "description": "MEAN.io: A fullstack JavaScript framework powered by MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, NodeJS.",
  "version": "0.4.3",
  "private": false,
  "author": "Linnovate <mean@linnovate.net>",
  "contributors": "https://github.com/linnovate/mean/graphs/contributors",
  "mean": "0.4.3",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.3.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "mocha": "node node_modules/.bin/mocha packages/**/server/tests/**/*.js -R spec -r tools/test/mocha-req.js",
    "karma": "node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "node node_modules/meanio/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-postinstall"
  },
```

I have Node: 0.10.33
       mean: 0.4.3
       mean-cli: 0.9.14
       mongo: 2.6.5

This is my Node log where very its very strange that requests are duplicated.

[image: It is very strange that requests are duplicated]

My network tab

Chrome: (Working and not working)
[image]

Firefox: (both Working and not Working)
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:

I have updated node, npm, mean, bower and gulp to the last version and although I get this error:

```
[Error: Module did not self-register.]
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Mean app started on port 3000 (development) cluster.worker.id: 0
```

the situation has improved: **now requests are made only one time**.

Comment: What does your network tab say?

Comment: I have edited the post by adding screenshots with tests both working (collegue laptop) and not working (My laptop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I realized that sudo npm install had gone wrong but I still do not know why. So, my solution was to copy a folder from my partner and to work with it.

Nevertheless, I have to examine node and npm installation in depth.